# ADOBE AIR Application - Right click can call a function?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I wonder if with a AIR app written in AS3 the right click on the scene can do other things that display a context menu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a [rightClick event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3arightClick)

Comment: So, it seems to be no more inconvenient to develop an AIR game.
Thank you !